# API v1 - Invalid API path to documented module/method

Tags: attributes, catalog, api

The API documentation describes some `product_attribute` methods that we can work with

(http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/catalogProductAttribute.html ).

These method names contradict what is configured in `Mage/Catalog/etc/api.xml`.

Documentation shows:

```
product_attribute.info
```

While the `api.xml` shows:

```
catalog_product_attribute.info
```

I am making a basic call using:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/api/?wsdl');
$session = $proxy->login($user, $pass);
$attribute = $proxy->call($session, 'product_attribute.info', $att_name);
// $attribute = $proxy->call($session, 'catalog_product_attribute.info', $att_name);
```

This results in the error, `Invalid API path`. If I change the API module/method to the commented line above, I get the same error.

What is the correct API v1 method to use to call product attribute methods?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with both the cases `product_attribute.info` and `catalog_product_attribute.info` and both of them got me the same result. The details of the attribute with the attribute code `$att_name`.
I tested with a php script and using SoapUi. Both of them worked.
Make sure you don't have custom modules that might affect the SOAP API.
I tested this on version 1.7.0.2. If you are using an other version please specify it in the question.